# Timer Not Ticking all the times

Tags: c#, timer, browser

So I declare this variables:

```
Timer timerSequencia;
Timer countdown;
Timer timer;

DateTime inicialTime;

TimeSpan sequenceInterval;
TimeSpan reloadDelay;
```

Then I start a timer:

```
//timer secs
countdown = new Timer();
countdown.Tick += new EventHandler(Countdown);
countdown.Interval = 1000;
```

Then when I click start:

```
if (sequence.Count == 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Não tem nenhuma instrução!", "Atenção!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
    return;
}

if (btnStart.Enabled == false)
{
    return;
}
inicialTime = DateTime.Now.Add(sequenceInterval);


timerSequencia.Start();
countdown.Start();

btnStart.Enabled = false;
btnStop.Enabled = true;
```

and i have a problem, it refresh every second sometimes, but sometimes it doesn't refresh. I have a webbrowser on the application, I don't know how to solve it, I've searched a lot already, if u want the program solution I can give it.

---

**Edit 1:**

What I really pretend with the program is the following: I have a WebBrowser and I want to make clicks on the page, because it is in flash I need to give a certain Point so it click in that Point, then 10 in 10 minutes it do that sequence but I have a timer to show how much time is left, so that refresh every second, the problem is that sometimes when I focus another window the timer stops and when I move my mouse, it shows a negative time (like it passed the 10 minutes to 15 minutes or 30 minutes like already happened)

I do a sendPost so its not necessary to have the windows focused when it is clicking

---

**Edit 2:**

So I've tried to use a thread to run the timer (in this case I've made a infinite while that call a method from the Form (main thread)) and I get the same problem as the Timer.

---

**Edit 3:**

I think I found the problem, its probably because the website I'm loading is in FLASH and it runs separately from the program and it "consumes" the all process of my program (I guess).

Comment: An overloaded web server or an occasionally slow Internet connection trivially explains that problem.  Make it 5 seconds instead.  Or disable the timer in the Tick event handler and re-enable it in the DocumentCompleted event handler.

Comment: Running the long running task in the UI thread is your problem

Comment: Sorry, didn't understood, the problem is that the Timer in the Main Form thread? How couldt i correct this?

Comment: The timer is used to trigger UI updates. It is in the right place. But it seems that you are blocking the main thread with your web browser control. That's the problem.

Comment: is there any simple solution? i cant use the WB in a thread lol

Comment: i cant find a solution to this problem, i've tested running a new thread that the only objective was an infinite loop calling a method at the Main Form to refresh the mouse position (so when i move the mouse it will say where the mouse is (X and Y pixels)) and when the web-browser starts loading, the thread freezes (the big problem here is that the website im loading is in flash and it never completes loading, its always doing something) I Would like to hear from you David Heffernan (or any other person that knows how to solve this) :)